# Are Starlink antennas portable for use across the globe during travel?

Tags: international-travel, internet

Starlink is slowly starting to spread their wings globally, with [a recent beta launched in Canada](https://www.pcmag.com/news/spacexs-starlink-can-start-serving-users-in-canada-regulator-says) after their initial launch in the US.

Let's assume I buy the antenna/dish and their service in Canada. If I decide to travel to the US for a holiday, can I take the equipment with me and use the same service there? More generally, once Starlink spreads globally, would it be possible to take my local product wherever I go and hook into their internet service wherever I land? Or is there something in their contract/setup that prohibits that kind of global travel use?

<sub>This question was originally asked on [Space.SE](//space.stackexchange.com) ([Portable Starlink antennas](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48810/38415)), but may be a better fit here as it relates more to travel than space exploration.</sub>

Comment: I expect them to offer a service like that eventually, possibly with different pricing tiers but it will still have limitations: there are countries where satellite phones/data services are forbidden or must be routed through local ground stations/use a locally registered number.

Comment: Is there a map of each cell to determine how far one can take the starlink terminal

Comment: @JosephDeAlmeida: I doubt it, but I'm not sure. The cells are probably somewhat overlapping to avoid discontinuities in service, but would require you to connect with SpaceX if you ever decide to move somewhere else, even just a different neighbourhood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: [As of April 2020](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2021/04/dishy-mcflatface-to-become-fully-mobile-allowing-starlink-use-away-from-home/), Musk tweeted that the service will be "fully mobile later this year." The company has announced, but not yet released, a terminal that permits use on moving vehicles. At this time, the terms of service restrict use to one location: "for use exclusively at the address you provided in your Order." Given the terminal's size and power requirements, there are still likely to be a number of constraints on portability for travel use, though service for RVs seems likely once this is available.

This was addressed [in the Q&A Starlink recently did on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Starlink/comments/jybmgn/we_are_the_starlink_team_ask_us_anything/gd3qsmx/):

> Right now, we can only deliver service at the address you sign up with on starlink.com You might get lucky if you try to use Starlink in nearby locations, but service quality may be worse.
>
> Mobility options - including moving your Starlink to different service addresses (or places that don't even have addresses!) - is coming once we are able to increase our coverage by launching more satellites & rolling out new software.

The beta service is currently [only offered to people](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/07/details-on-spacex-starlink-beta-emerge-along-with-photos-of-user-terminals/) "between 44 and 52 degrees north latitude, which excludes a good portion of the United States. I believe this is supposed to expand as the constellation reaches its full size.

There are also some pretty stringent requirements around [avoiding obstructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/Starlink/comments/jybmgn/we_are_the_starlink_team_ask_us_anything/gd2d96y/) between the dish and the satellites, and the terminal equipment doesn't look particularly portable, so there would be some practical issues around trying to transport it and finding a suitable place to set it up with a view of the sky that meets the requirements.

In short, it may not work for a number of reasons right now. They say they plan to support more portability in the future, which may or may not work out.

It is possible to get portable satellite internet service on networks like HughesNet (purchased through specialized resellers that cater to RVers I believe, and not really in Canada) or (more portable with a vast coverage area but at extraordinary cost) with a BGAN terminal, Inmarsat, and there are vendors that will rent them out with service for travelers, but the costs are high and the speeds quite slow.

Comment: Between 44 and 52 degrees covers a pretty big chunk of Europe - Stockholm, London, Paris, Frankfurt, Vienna, Milan. Would be nice to use it while hiking in the Alps :)

Comment: @JonathanReez From what I understand, to get service the satellite(s) need to be in sight from your location but also of a ground station, so I suppose it won’t work in Europe at all for now. Also the antenna has a diameter of 50 cm, not exactly something you want to carry while hiking.

Comment: @JonathanReez Don't forget to pack along your 100W power supply - that's a number I recently saw for powering a Starlink ground station.  I would suggest that you employ a team sherpas to carry around the 500VA to 1000VA batteries needed for for the system.  Employ enough of them and you could get them rotating the batteries to places where the batteries could be charged in order to have continuous Starlink operation in the boonies.  Either that or go solar, but those pesky Alps may not allow for a suitable, portable solar setup.

Comment: @jcaron: The *ground station* you're referring to, is that the dish? Sure, my intent was never to hike from (say) Canada to (say) the US or abroad, but ultimately to stash that thing in a travel suitcase (maybe) so I can use it wherever I land.

Comment: @Werner Yes, the dish itself is actually 59cm in diameter.  The base mounting pole is also integrated into the dish (which seems to contain electronics and motors for tracking the satellites).  By the looks of it you'll probably need a suitcase just for the antenna and associated external systems for it.  There are already a bunch of tear down videos on youtube (such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QudtSo5tpLk) )

Comment: @PeterM: I didn't know there was a mounting pole integrated into the physical dish. It makes sense now that installation is specific to your location. I assume next generation receivers will become more portable with ways to update the configuration based on ones location, as people relocate all the time and shouldn't be restricted to your purchased lat/long.

Comment: From the videos I've seen, the starlink kit comes with both a free-standing base and a bolt down base. So you don't have to permanently install it to use it. It's not clear to me if there is a way to tell it to move back to the position it ships in though so you can get it back in the box.

Comment: @Werner, no, the ground station I’m referring to is the Starlink network gateway between the satellites and the rest of the Internet. Ultimately satellites are supposed to have inter-satellite links, but given the constellation is far from complete it seems the satellite you talk to currently just relays between you and a ground station, so both must be visible at the same time, and there’s a limited number of them right now (remember the satellites are in relatively low orbit so they don’t see much of the Earth surface at any given time).

Comment: It’s also quite possible (especially given the wording) that one’s traffic is only routed through a single gateway, so if you move to another location, even if there is a gateway around, you won’t receive anything. Of course that’s not the final situation, but at the moment there seems to be quite a few issues with moving the terminal to a different location.

Comment: While the equipment seems like too much to haul into the mountains I can see a market for putting it on a RV.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Zach's answer that referenced the Q&A on Reddit, the [Starlink Beta FAQ](https://www.starlink.com/faq) has this to say about moving the base station

> **Can I travel with Starlink, or move it to a different address?**
>
> Starlink satellites are scheduled to send internet down to all users
> within a designated area on the ground. This designated area is
> referred to as a cell.
>
> Your Starlink is assigned to a single cell. If you move your Starlink
> outside of its assigned cell, a satellite will not be scheduled to
> serve your Starlink and you will not receive internet. This is
> constrained by geometry and is not arbitrary geofencing.

---

**Edit - New information from SpaceX**

This week (8th March 2021) SpaceX filed that a Starlink terminal could be deployed on vehicles.  See [this](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2021/03/spacex-plans-starlink-broadband-for-cars-boats-and-planes) story about that filing.

However a lot of people took this to mean even on things as small as  passenger cars, however Elon corrected this is a [tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1369051431903268865) saying:

> Not connecting Tesla cars to Starlink, as our terminal is much too
> big. This is for aircraft, ships, large trucks & RVs.

So in the future you will be able to use your starlink device on your RV as you drive across the US, or on your boat as you cruise the intercostal waterway.  But no indication was given as to when this might be possible.

**Edit - More information from Elon Musk**

I saw in [this article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2021/04/dishy-mcflatface-to-become-fully-mobile-allowing-starlink-use-away-from-home/) that Elon [tweeted](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1382842277719003136) this week (15th of April 2021)

> Yeah, should be fully mobile later this year, so you can move it
> anywhere or use it on an RV or truck in motion. We need a few more
> satellite launches to achieve compete coverage & some key software
> upgrades.

Comment: I'd note that as long as your car can fit the antenna, you can move it around. Starlink doesn't literally check if you're driving an RV or not.

Answer (score 3):

> If I decide to travel to the US for a holiday, can I take the equipment with me

Yes but it has an extra monthly fee https://www.starlink.com/rv USD 25 at the time of this writing. It doesn't work while moving, at this time that is yet another special service, aimed at boats and requires entirely different equipment and different monthly fees -- 10 000 USD one time fee and 5000 USD monthly.

> and use the same service there?

Almost but not quite. https://www.cnbc.com/2022/05/05/spacex-adds-25-portability-monthly-fee-for-starlink-service.html says “Starlink prioritizes network resources for users at their registered service address. When you bring your Starlink to a new location, this prioritization may result in degraded service, particularly at times of peak usage or network congestion,” so you will get service on a best effort basis, ”with the company’s advertised speeds of 100 Mbps to 200 Mbps not guaranteed”.

> More generally, once Starlink spreads globally, would it be possible to take my local product wherever I go and hook into their internet service wherever I land?

My understanding the above is global.

> Or is there something in their contract/setup that prohibits that kind of global travel use?

There is as the other answers show but some people [tweeted](https://twitter.com/heydave7/status/1521490645004730370) they moved their equipment and it worked. While this was in breach of their contract SpaceX just decided to ignore it. I can think of two reasons:

1. at a "remote state park" which is so remote there's no cell reception there are just not enough customers whom such rogue roaming would disturb.
2. at the time there was no "RV" option yet.

Answer (score 2):

> Are Starlink antennas portable for use across the globe during travel?

Yes for sea travel: [SpaceX's Starlink launches $5,000-per-month satellite internet for yachts](https://sports.yahoo.com/spacexs-starlink-launches-5-000-223043046.html)

More info on https://www.starlink.com/maritime:

> High-speed, low-latency internet with up to 350 Mbps download while at sea. US$5,000/mo with a one-time hardware cost of US$10,000 for two high performance terminals.

Coverage: https://api.starlink.com/public-files/maritime-coverage-map.pdf.

Satellites: https://satellitemap.space/

Comment: plus an initial $10,000 fee

Answer (score 1):

Tesla’s have a 70-100kWh battery in them.
Should power the base station for a good long time.
Good for camping.
Not so much for hiking, though.

Comment: Unfortunate though if you run down your battery powering your satellite base station, and don't have enough energy left to drive back to civilization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have guests in our RV Park that are using Starlink. The downside of being mobile is that traffic is de-prioritized. So at night folks are reporting speeds of 1-2mbps download. I believe this is at the $150/mo rate. For $250/mo USD the speed is not de-prioritized. Some long-term guests have switched to our RV Park fiber internet service because of the slowdown.